# Error: Problem validating asset fields in app.json when file path should be correct

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm pretty new to React Native/Expo CLI, and I'm trying to publish my app for the first time. When running the `expo publish` command in my terminal, I get this error :

```
Error: Problem validating asset fields in app.json. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/
 • Field: splash.image - cannot access file at './app/assets/splash.png'.
 • Field: icon - cannot access file at './app/assets/icon.png'.
 • Field: android.adaptiveIcon.foregroundImage - cannot access file at './app/assets/adaptive-icon.png'.
Couldn't publish because errors were found. (See logs above.) Please fix the errors and try again.
```

From my understanding, thhis indicates that Expo couldn't find the files in the path provided in the app.json file. However, the paths I gave are correct. Here's my app.json file:

[image]

And here are my project files :

[image]

Anybody understands why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your png files are in "./app/assets/image" folder instead of "./app/assets/"

can you change  `'./app/assets/splash.png'.` with `'./app/assets/image/splash.png'.`  and try again,

also do same for other images too...